# Customizing the look and feel of Orbeon forms

Tags: orbeon

We would like to be able to customize the areas outside the form elements area itself, such that customers can have all their forms including the areas surrounding the form in their own style. For instance in the area on the top we would like to have a different color and we would like to replace the Orbeon logo by the logo of the customer. Also we would like to hide/remove/customize some buttons that appear below the form. For instance we don't need the buttons for PDF, Email and Close and we want to change the text in the Save button to Submit.

Is that possible? If so, how do we do that? Is there some instruction somewhere for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do all of this through properties:

1. You can change the color at the top by overriding the `.fr-top` rule defined in `form-runner-orbeon.css`. For more on how to override CSS, see: [Default CSS](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/styling/css).
2. You can replace or remove the default logo with the `oxf.fr.default-logo.uri.*.*` property. See [Default logo](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-runner#default-logo).
3. You can choose which buttons are shown on the Form Runner "details" page by overriding the `oxf.fr.detail.buttons.*.*` property. See [Buttons on the detail page](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-runner/form-runner-detail-page#buttons-on-the-detail-page).
4. You can change the label on a button by overriding resources. See [Overriding resources](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-runner#overriding-resources).

Comment: Thanks! Good to see that Orbeon provides in these.

Comment: If you like the answer can you mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: Here is a follow up on the original question. In the form and outside the form orbeon also uses graphical elements (images). How can these be customized?

Comment: Bonna, whenever possible, we use background images set using CSS. If you are in one of those cases, then you can override the default CSS rule in your own CSS. Otherwise, if an actual `<img>` is generated, you'll have to change the XSLT that generates that image. Do you have a specific image you'd like to change in mind?

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with the problem to change the icon in the browser address and found the answer of Alessandro Vernet:
http://discuss.orbeon.com/page-address-bar-browser-icon-td4660752.html .
But this solution has the drawback  that I had to change the `orbeon-form-runner.jar`, and this with every new orbeon forms release, what I wanted to avoid.
So the idea was to give my icons the same name as the orbeon icons and to load them in a corresponding directory of the resource directory. 
So I named my icon  `orbeon-icon-16.ico` and `orbeon-icon-16.png` and loaded the two files in `orbeon/WEB-INF/resources/ops/images`.
For Firefox this was OK, but IE continued to show the orbeon icon. Then I noticed that in orbeon-core.jar there where also the 32 pixel icon.
So I added the two files orbeon-icon-32.ico and orbeon-icon-32.png  and than also IE was showing our icon.

[image: directory and filelist]